# Rendering an animated GIF in Garmin Connect IQ

Tags: connectiq

According to the documentation (https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/resource-compiler/) the resource compiler supports GIF as Bitmap. However, when I display a GIF file, I just get a still picture, and the GIF doesn't move.

The GIF I have been testing with is this: http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Mammals/Cats/cats/cute-kitty-animated-gif-2.gif
and I have saved the gif in the drawables folder (I use the ConnectIQ-plugin for Eclipse).

I have tried to include the Bitmap in the layouts resources as:

```
<layout id="MainLayout">
    <bitmap id="MotivatorCat" x="center" y="center" filename="../drawables/motivatorcat.gif"/>
</layout>
```

and I have tried to include it in the drawables resources as:

```
<drawables>
    <bitmap id="MotivatorCat" filename="motivatorcat.gif" />
</drawables>
```

and then loading it in initialize() by:

```
catgif = Ui.loadResource(Rez.Drawables.MotivatorCat);
```

and drawing it in onUpdate():

```
dc.drawBitmap(50, 50, catgif);
```

But nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Connect IQ does not currently (as of SDK 2.1.x) support rendering of animated GIF images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that you have changed it from your original answer which was pretty much a rewrite of what I had already written in the question description - about the two things I had tried to do.

I don't see why my question is down voted though. I think one of the big advantages of a GIF is that it supports animations, so it would be reasonable to think that the Connect IQ would support animated GIFs when the documentation says that it supports GIFs.

Anyway, I have now made my own animation with a series of updates to the view with different pictures.

Comment: I didn't vote your question down so I'm not sure. I changed my answer because your original question title (before I edited it) didn't mention the fact that you were trying to animate the image and I missed that.